# ng-show javascript variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I try to set value of javascript variable `js_var` to angularjs variable `example_var` which is bind to `ng-show` directive.

Value is right, but `ng-show` does not works. If I hardcode value of `example_var` the `ng-show` directive works(e.g. `$scope.example_var = true;`). I try to fix it and I found on stackoverflow example with `$scope.$apply(function())`, but it won`t help.

I set in my controller value (`$scope.example_var = js_var;`).

```
<div ng-show="example_var">...</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: show your code which will show the partial declaration of the variable and your markup fully

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VNynPcYX

Comment: your setup should work, except that you mentioned that you get your value from the backend. For this you need to work with promises (`$http`) since the data arrives asynchronously

Comment: Some error is shown in the console?

Comment: @Arem is the js_var coming from an ajax call or is that being set during rendering of the page? If it is set during page render, I would recommend using `ng-init`, ie `ng-init="initFunc(js_var)"` to pass the value to your controller. If it is with an ajax call, I'd recommend moving that call in to your controller and using the angular `$http`.

Comment: So maybe I will be more specific. The problem is that checkbox is always false and after 2-4 clicks ng-show start working. https://pastebin.com/9GfMWny2

Comment: You should use something like [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) instead of pastebin...

Comment: try doing `$timeout( function() {$scope.example_var = js_var } )` in your controller